# ORA-1034 Oracle Not Found

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I have recently installed oracle 11g on Windows 7 Home Premium Operating System. I logged in as administrator into windows. I am trying to create a database using DBCA wizard. I started the wizard as administrator. Everything goes fine until last step. However when creating the database the creation fails with `ORA-01034 Oracle Not Available error`. All my oracle services looks up and running. I consulted the documentation and forums. I have got no clue why I am running into the error.

Answer (score 2):

Did you look [here](http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/Local_Login_to_Oracle_Database)?

A quote:

> When DBCA is used to create or
>   configure the database, the
>   corresponding entry for the listener
>   name alias is NOT automatically added
>   to the tnsnames.ora file

Make sure the entry for the listener name alias specified by the LOCAL_LISTENER exists in the TNSNAMES.ORA file.

Answer (score 0):

Before running DBCA, can you start LISTENER with `lsnrctl start` command?

You can find this tool in $ORACLE_HOME/bin.

If any config(LISTENER.ora) isn't created then this command will create it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ensure the listener is in fact running:

```
root@localhost~] $ su - oracle
oracle@localhost~]$ lnsrctl start #this will run your default listener
```

If you have a specific named listener, then you must specify the name.  For example, I have listener1 for starting my Finance database, so I will start this listener with the following command:

```
syntax lsnrctl start <listener name>
oracle@localhost~]$lsnrctl strart Listener1
```